# To italicize or not?

Tags: writing

I am writing a novel set in 12th century France in English. I have included, for flavor, only a sprinkling of French words commonly known to English readers.
 I'm questioning the typeset of "chevalier". Although I needn't italicize a noun identical in both languages, would doing so lead my reader to the French pronunciation of shə-ˈval-ˌyā rather than the English use of she-və-ˈlir? Or shall I consider myself guilty of overthinking and leave it to a standard font?
Your thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Is *chevalier* an English word? I think not, though it may often be found in English texts.

Comment: @WS2 [Oxford Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chevalier) thinks so.

Comment: I think readers who know French or even have a certain sense of it would be more inclined to pronounce it in French if it was italicized.

Comment: I agree with @Jim here. If I saw the word chevalier in an English text, I’d pronounce it [ˌʃεvəˈlɪə]; if I saw the word _chevalier_ in an English text set in 12th-century France, I’d (anachronistically) pronounce it [ʃəvalˈje]. I would never, no matter how you wrote it, pronounce it [ʃəˈvalˌjεɪ] (= what you write as _shəˈval-ˌyā_), since that’s neither French nor English.

Comment: @bib I stand corrected. The OED certainly treats it as though it were an English word: 
1691   A. Wood Athenæ Oxonienses I. 164   Carried to his grave by 4 Irish chevaliers.

1848   E. Bulwer-Lytton Harold I. i. iii. 54   Sacred abbots and noble chevaliers—Normans all.

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) lists *chevalier* as an anglicized term, meaning that no italics are needed to distinguish the word from English vocabulary words—unlike the situation with, for example, *écuyer* (the French equivalent of "squire" or "equerry"), which is not anglicized in its French spelling.

But having determined that you don't have to italicize *chevalier*, you are still free as a matter of style (assuming that you aren't answerable to someone else's house style on this point) to italicize certain borrowings from other languages if you like the effect that it produces.

My only two warnings in this regard are commonsensical to the point of obviousness:

1. Don't flood your pages with italicized versions of every English word that came from French—such as *bouquet*, *cuisine*, and *naïveté*.
2. If you decide to italicize a particular word (like *chevalier*), do it consistently throughout the book.

My own tendency is to pronounce *chevalier* as I would Maurice Chevalier's last name, whether it's italicized or not. I think of *cavalier* as the all-purpose, standard English equivalent, and when *chevalier* shows up, I am already halfway to sounding it out à la Pepé Le Pew. But other readers' interpretations will differ—so, as they say, "Sank hevvens for leetle font treatments!"

Comment: Thanks! I have only a few italicized French words that come up so I've decided to keep chevalier in italics for effect. Sank hevvens, seneschal is also an Anglicized term :)